# Number of matrices $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ where $A^2 = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics

What is the number of matrices $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for which $A^2 = 0$ (as a function of $n$ and $q$)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add the upvote.

Comment: Is $q$ intended to be a prime or a prime power here?  Have you tried the case $q=2$?

Answer (score 5):

I will let you write the details, this is just a sketch.

Even if we are not in an algebraically closed field, we can always conjugate those matrices to their canonical Jordan form (why?).

Then try to understand what are the possible canonical Jordan form verifying this condition (easy).

Then compute the centralizer of each matrix obtained (this is possible, given any Jordan form to compute the centralizer), in particular you will have the cardinal of each.

Deduce from this the cardinality of each conjugacy class, the sum of all those cardinals will exactly give you  what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are $p,r$ s.t. $A$ is similar over $\mathbb{F}_q$ to $U_{p,r}=diag(V_1,\cdots,V_p,0_r)$ where $V_i=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $2p+r=n$. Let $\alpha_{p,r}$ be the cardinality of the centralizer of $U_{p,r}$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, that is $card(\{P\in GL_n;PU_{p,r}=U_{p,r}P\})$.

Note that $\{P\in M_n;PU_{p,r}=U_{p,r}P\}$ is a vector space of dimension $2p^2+2pr+r^2$; yet $\alpha_{p,r}$ is difficult to calculate; that is the sole difficulty of the problem and Clement did not rack his brains on the subject!

It is known that $card(GL_n)=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots(q^n-q^{n-1})$; then the cardinality of the conjugacy class of $U_{p,r}$ is $\beta_{p,r}=\dfrac{card(GL_n)}{\alpha_{p,r}}$. Finally, the required result is $\sum_{2p+r=n}\beta_{p,r}$.

Some results. For $n=2,3,4$, we obtain $q^2,q^4+q^3-q,q^8+q^6-q^2$.