# Number of matrices X^2 = 0 over F_q?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

What is number of matrices X^2 = 0 over F_q ?

PS

That should be very well-known, but how to google it ?

---

---

---

PS

Some related results:

number of nilpotent n × n matrices over the finite field Fq is q^(n(n−1))
Quote: "Essentially, the same argument can be
used to establish the result of Fine and Herstein [Illinois J. Math. 2 (1958) 499–504] that the
number of nilpotent n × n matrices over the finite field Fq is q^(n(n−1))."

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82519026.pdf
Research note
Counting nilpotent endomorphisms
M.C. Crabb
Department of Mathematical Sciences, University of Aberdeen, Aberdeen, AB24 3UE, UK
Received 9 December 2003; revised 21 February 2005

Alternative proof was given by Gerstenhaber:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-5/issue-2/On-the-number-of-nilpotent-matrices-with-coefficients-in-a/10.1215/ijm/1255629831.full
On the number of nilpotent matrices with coefficients in a finite field
Murray Gerstenhaber
Author Affiliations +
Illinois J. Math. 5(2): 330-333 (June 1961).

Alternative interpretation:
https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2019/12/counting_nilpotents.html
What is the probability that a random linear operator is nilpotent?

Recall that a linear operator T on a vector space V is called “nilpotent” if Tn=0 for some n. Assuming that V is finite-dimensional and over a finite field, there are only finitely many operators on V. Choose one at random. It turns out that the probability of it being nilpotent is

1#V

— the reciprocal of the number of elements of V.

q^(2v) = count unipotent elements for G , v - number of roots , (theorem of Steinberg)
A Note on Counting Nilpotent Matrices of Fixed Rank
G. Lusztig
Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society, Volume 8, Issue 1, March 1976, Pages 77–80, https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/8.1.77
Published: 01 March 1976

Comment: *Hint*: $X\in M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, $X^2=0$ iff $X$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}^{\oplus k}\oplus \begin{pmatrix}0\end{pmatrix}^{\oplus(n-2k)}$, so just count the sizes of the $GL(n,q)$ orbits.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415707/number-of-matrices-a-in-m-n-mathbbf-q-where-a2-0/1415807#1415807